# Magento tags collection for multiple products

Tags: php, magento, tags

My PHP knowledge is somewhat limited and I'm working with Magento 1.9.3.

I need to display a tags collection from multiple products and I don't understand why this code doesn't work:

```
//List of my products
$displayProduct = $this->getCollection();
ob_start();
foreach ($displayProduct as $_product) { 
    echo ($_product->getId().','); 
}
$output = substr(ob_get_clean(), 0, -1);
echo $output;

// Tags list
$model = Mage::getModel('tag/tag'); 
$TaGCollection = $model->getResourceCollection() 
    ->addPopularity() 
    ->addProductFilter(array($output))
    ->setFlag('relation', true) 
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()
    ->getStore()->getId()) 
    ->limit(30)
    ->setActiveFilter()
    ->load();
```

The first collection displays this list of products ids correctly:

```
548,549,650,675,676,686,761,534,535,533,766,767,768,772,778,783,786,790,794,814,818
```

If I paste this list as array values in the second collection it works. But when I insert the variable `$output` in the second collection it doesn't work.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

```
   //List of my products
   $displayProduct = $this->getCollection();
   $output = array();  /declaration as an arraY
   foreach ($displayProduct as $_product) { 
       array_push($output,$_product);  //PUSH Product Ids in $output 
   }



    // Tags list
    $model = Mage::getModel('tag/tag'); 
    $TaGCollection = $model->getResourceCollection() 
           ->addPopularity() 
           ->addProductFilter($output)
           ->setFlag('relation', true) 
           ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()
           ->getStore()->getId()) 
           ->limit(30)
           ->setActiveFilter()
           ->load();
```

Answer (score 0):

//Get the collection of products

```
$displayProduct = $this->getCollection();
$output = array();  //declaration as an array
foreach ($displayProduct as $_product) { 
array_push($output,$_product->getId());  //PUSH Product Ids in $output 
}
```

// Get Tags By Product ids, that is based on $output variable

```
$model = Mage::getModel('tag/tag'); 
$TagCollection = $model->getResourceCollection() 
->addPopularity() 
->addProductFilter($output)
->setFlag('relation', true) 
->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()
->getStore()->getId()) 
->limit(30)
->setActiveFilter()
->load();
```

Then loop through the $TagCollection to get tags one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this solution really works:

```
//List of my products
$displayProduct = $this->getCollection();
ob_start();
foreach ($displayProduct as $_product) { 
    echo ($_product->getId().', '); 
}
$output = substr(ob_get_clean(), 0, -2);
$productIds = explode(', ', trim($output));

// Tags list
$model = Mage::getModel('tag/tag'); 
$TaGCollection = $model->getResourceCollection() 
    ->addPopularity() 
    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', array('in' => $productIds))
    ->setFlag('relation', true) 
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()
    ->getStore()->getId()) 
    ->limit(30)
    ->setActiveFilter()
    ->load();
```

Thanks for your answers!! :)